# Show that $X$ has the same homology as a sphere $S^{n}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Recently I have been taking the Algebraic Topology course.
I have no idea how to solve this problem in my assignment sheet.

> Suppose $X$ is a path-connected (based) space, $M$ is a compact orientable manifold, and $f: S^{1} \wedge X \rightarrow M$ is a map inducing an isomorphism on homology with integer coefficients. Show that $X$ has the same homology as a sphere $S^{n}$.

The professor gave a hint:

> Besides Poincaré duality, need to use the fact that the cup product is 0 on $S^{1} \wedge X$ (recall relative cup products).

However, I still cannot solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you will find it useful to know that the top deRham cohomology of any compact connected and orientable manifold is $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @quickquestion4 Thank you, but my professor have not taught the de Rham cohomology yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the universal coefficient theorem for cohomology you can conclude that $$f^*:H^k(M;\mathbb Z) \rightarrow H^k(S^1\wedge X;\mathbb Z)$$ is an isomorphism since the long exact sequence is functorial (even if the splitting is not). 
 It follows that  $$f^*:H^*(M;\mathbb Z)\rightarrow H^*(S^1\wedge X; \mathbb Z) $$ is an isomorphism of rings. 
 But $S^1\wedge X$ has trivial cup product in positive degrees. Hence so does $M$. 
Now recall Poincare duality. $$H^k(M;\mathbb Z)\times H^{n-k}(M;\mathbb Z)\rightarrow \mathbb Z$$ $$(\alpha,\beta)\mapsto (\alpha \smile \beta )[M]$$ is a perfect pairing. It follows that $H^k(M;\mathbb Z)=0$ if $0<k<n$ and hence $H^k(S^1\wedge X;\mathbb Z)=0$ if $0<k<n$. 
 Now you can use Kunneth formula to compute the cohomology of $S^1\times X$ in terms of the cohomology of $X$. You can also compute the cohomology of $S^1\vee X$. Then use the long exact sequence in cohomology on the pair $(S^1\times X,S^1\vee X)$.

Comment: Thank you, but are there any conclusions about cohomology on the smash product of $S^1 \wedge X$, or more generally, two topological spaces?

Comment: The cohomology groups can be computed fairly easily I think using the Kunneth formula and the cohomology long exact sequence. Also observe that if $X$ and $Y$ are CW complexes and you give $X\times Y$ the usual product CW complex structure, then $X\vee Y$ sits as a sub-complex. In that case you have an explicit CW complex structure on $X\wedge Y= X\times Y/ X\vee Y$

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot.